QGIS security/patches
Our government agency is interested in running QGIS on prem. They are interested in the vulnerability in QGIS section (https://www.qgis.org/resources/support/security/).
Any recommendation on best practice in keeping the QGIS app as much secure as possible?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, which is not quite compatible with recommendations on best practices, which tend to be subjective and opinion-based. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Part of the "cost" of free software is reviewing the documentation and doing the system integration tasks yourself. Please [Edit] the Question to state what have you tried, and where are you stuck.

According to the doc you linked to, keep the software up to date and, if you need to, restrict python plugins (basically block QGIS plugin repo and then self host your own plugin repo).
